# Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app': Cannot find module 'eslint'

Tags: webpack, node-modules, eslint, lib, eslintrc

Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app': Cannot find module 'eslint'
Require stack:

- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\ExportMap.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\rules\named.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\index.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules@eslint\eslintrc\lib\config-array-factory.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules@eslint\eslintrc\lib\index.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\index.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\getESLint.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\linter.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\eslint-webpack-plugin\dist\cjs.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- E:\Quora-project\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js

How to fix the Error. then view the Output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.